# Timer doesn't work correclty in listview

Tags: android, timer

I have an instance of ListView that contains items. Each item has a Timer for StopWatching.

```
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tempTime++;
                Log.i(get_id() + "",tempTime + "");
            }
        }, 0,1000);
```

In activity

```
upTime.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            UpdateTimes();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });


                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

I gave period parameter 1 sec. I created another timer in activity to update ListView, But in the LogOut prints sooner than 1 sec. I can say its period is about 50 milli sec.

What's problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show time in your list-view or any where in your project then use chronometer in android, it will handle your timer and you can manage it by start and stop method.

Use chronometer to show time:

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:textColor="#4169E1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Chronometer" />
```

In your class :

```
Chronometer focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
```

To start :

```
focus.start();
```

To stop :

```
focus.stop();
```

To Restart :

```
focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

To set formate:

```
focus.setFormat("Formated Time - %s");
```

for more detail please follow below link:

http://sampleprogramz.com/android/chronometer.php
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html
I hope it will help.